# Keeping iOS webpage alive

Tags: javascript, php, ios

So I'd like to update my database with new data every 30 seconds while I've got Safari running my page in the background. As soon as I have Safari opened, it refreshes everything successfully and the data will be stored.

However, as soon as I have Safari running in the background with the page open, it does not store the data since the page isn't 'live'.

I've tried several things, even looping background music since the background music will be played on the background. But that doesnt keep my javascript alive.

This is my page setup:

**On the main page:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

var audio = document.getElementById('background_music');
//document.getElementById("background_music").muted = true;
audio.play();

    $('#wrapper._location').load("/loc/content/loc-data.php");

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#wrapper._location').load("/loc/content/loc-data.php");
        console.log('refreshed');
      }, 12000);

 });
```

**Below** the loc-data.php content

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/db-requests/loc/db-store-loc.php",
            data: {loc_name: loc_name, loc_inner: loc_inner},
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finish_loc_storage(data,textStatus,jqXHR);  }
        });

});
```

Is there any way to keep everything alive on the background so the data will be stored in my database?

THank you.

Comment: why you don't put the AJAX function below directly into the setInterval function in your main page?

Comment: Should be done server side not client side

Comment: @Dagon So basically it is not possible to do this?